# Character vs Integer Arithmetic

Tags: c, math, rsa

This is related to another question, but I believe I figured out the problem to that one and now have this problem. It seems that I can do arithmetic operations properly on a `uint8_t` but not on an `unsigned char`. I am unsure as to why this may be, as `unsigned char` should be equivalent to `uint8_t` to my understanding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

/*

gcc -o ./rsacalc ./rsacalc.c
./rsacalc 1 2 3

should produce 00:00 but usually seems to produce 03:00

*/

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned char sg, sk, sm;
    uint8_t ng, nk, nm;
    if ( argc != 4 ) return 0;

    sg = argv[1][0];
    sk = argv[2][0];
    sm = argv[3][0];

    ng = atoi(argv[1]);
    nk = atoi(argv[2]);
    nm = atoi(argv[3]);

    printf("%.2X:%.2X\n",
        ((sg ^ sk) % sm),
        ((ng ^ nk) % nm)
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this

```
sg = argv[1][0];
sk = argv[2][0];
sm = argv[3][0];
```

here you are assigning the [ASCII codes](https://www.asciitable.com/) of `'1'` (49), `'2'` (50) and `'3'` (51). Note that `'1' != 1`. You are doing arithmetic with
different values, of course the results will be different. It has nothing to do
with the types.

The correct version should be

```
sg = argv[1][0] - '0';
sk = argv[2][0] - '0';
sm = argv[3][0] - '0';
```

Comment: The problem is originally from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328161/linux-memory-allocation-free-issues

I am not sure if that helps, but in the linked question the code does not care about the ascii value as a character. Or am I misunderstanding that? Should I just cast to uint8_t or atoi() on each related line? It just seems like a whole lot of conversion going on.

Comment: @KatyaVeselnitskaya I don't see the connection with your other question. I haven't read your other code in detail, but you might be mixing ascii codes with the numbers again. As I said `'1' != 1`.

Comment: Well maybe it's not related. I can accept your answer in a few minutes.

Comment: One thing I noticed in your other code: the `a_*` arrays are not initialized, `symm[n] = ((gb_key[n] ^ priv[n]) % mod[n]);` is working with uninitialized values, that yield undefined behaviour

Comment: well I just tried adding `memset(variable, 0, RSAKEYSIZE);` to each of them and it is same results.